# How do I validate SQL tables data using a schema

Tags: sql-server, xml, validation, sql-server-2012, schema

My understanding is poor so really need a place to start looking for information.

I have 4 SQL tables of data. I would like to output all of them to an XML file.

I have an XML Schema to work with but no idea how to use it or where it should be used.

Long term objective is to have 30 hand off tables which we can run validation scripts against and then using the XML Scheme given generate 1 XML file for submission.

I am a novice here and learning as I go so any suggestions where to look would be appreciated.

SAMPLE XML DATA

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Sample XML file generated by XMLSpy v2013 rel. 2 sp2 (http://www.altova.com)-->
-<MSDS:MSDS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:MSDS="http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/messages/MSDS-v1-0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/messages/MSDS-v1-0 ../Schemas/MSDSMSDS_XMLSchema-v1-0.xsd">

-<MATHDRHeader>

<Version>1.0</Version>
<OrgCodeProv>5BC</OrgCodeProv>
<OrgCodeSubmitter>YEA</OrgCodeSubmitter>
<RPStartDate>2013-01-01</RPStartDate>
<RPEndDate>2013-03-12</RPEndDate>
<FileCreationDateTime>2013-03-13T13:00:27</FileCreationDateTime>
<RecordCount>1</RecordCount>


-<MAT001MothersDemographics>

<LocalPatientIdMother>112552254</LocalPatientIdMother>
<OrgCodeLocalPatientIdMother>5BC</OrgCodeLocalPatientIdMother>
<OrgCodeRes>5BC</OrgCodeRes>
<NHSNumberMother>1111111111</NHSNumberMother>
<NHSNumberStatusMother>01</NHSNumberStatusMother>
<PersonBirthDateMother>1982-01-05</PersonBirthDateMother>
<Postcode>LS1 4HY</Postcode>
<EthnicCategoryMother>99</EthnicCategoryMother>
<PersonDeathDateTimeMother>1900-01-01T00:00:00</PersonDeathDateTimeMother>


-<MAT003GPPracticeRegistration>

<LocalPatientIdMother>112552254</LocalPatientIdMother>
<OrgCodeGMPMother>4RT</OrgCodeGMPMother>
<StartDateGMPRegistration>2012-01-06</StartDateGMPRegistration>
<EndDateGMPRegistration>1900-01-01</EndDateGMPRegistration>
<OrgCodeCommissioner>6TY</OrgCodeCommissioner>
</MAT003GPPracticeRegistration>


-<MAT101BookingAppointmentDetails>

<AntenatalAppDate>2013-03-01</AntenatalAppDate>
<LocalPatientIdMother>112552254</LocalPatientIdMother>
<EDDAgreed>2013-05-01</EDDAgreed>
<EDDMethodAgreed>01</EDDMethodAgreed>
<PregnancyFirstContactDate>2013-11-11</PregnancyFirstContactDate>
<PregnancyFirstContactCareProfessionalType>060</PregnancyFirstContactCareProfessionalType>
<LastMenstrualPeriodDate>2012-10-01</LastMenstrualPeriodDate>
<PhysicalDisabilityStatusIndMother>Y</PhysicalDisabilityStatusIndMother>
<FirstLanguageEnglishIndMother>Y</FirstLanguageEnglishIndMother>
<EmploymentStatusMother>04</EmploymentStatusMother>
<SupportStatusMother>Y</SupportStatusMother>
<EmploymentStatusPartner>06</EmploymentStatusPartner>
<PreviousCaesareanSections>0</PreviousCaesareanSections>
<PreviousLiveBirths>0</PreviousLiveBirths>
<PreviousStillBirths>0</PreviousStillBirths>
<PreviousLossesLessThan24Weeks>0</PreviousLossesLessThan24Weeks>
<SubstanceUseStatus>01</SubstanceUseStatus>
<SmokingStatus>03</SmokingStatus>
<CigarettesPerDay>0</CigarettesPerDay>
<AlcoholUnitsPerWeek>0</AlcoholUnitsPerWeek>
<FolicAcidSupplement>03</FolicAcidSupplement>
<MHPredictionDetectionIndMother>N</MHPredictionDetectionIndMother>
<PersonWeight>75.0</PersonWeight>
<PersonHeight>1.45</PersonHeight>
<ComplexSocialFactorsInd>N</ComplexSocialFactorsInd>

</MAT101BookingAppointmentDetails>

</MATHDRHeader>

</MSDS:MSDS>
```

SAMPLE XDS

```
 <xs:complexType name="MSDSMAT001MothersDemographicsType">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="LocalPatientIdMother" type="ST" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:annotation>
               <xs:appinfo>LOCAL PATIENT IDENTIFIER (MOTHER)</xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="OrgCodeLocalPatientIdMother" type="ST" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:annotation>
               <xs:appinfo>ORGANISATION CODE (LOCAL PATIENT IDENTIFIER (MOTHER))</xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="OrgCodeRes" type="ST" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:annotation>
               <xs:appinfo>ORGANISATION CODE (RESIDENCE RESPONSIBILITY)</xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="NHSNumberMother" type="ST" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:annotation>
               <xs:appinfo>NHS NUMBER (MOTHER)</xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="NHSNumberStatusMother" type="ST" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:annotation>
               <xs:appinfo>NHS NUMBER STATUS INDICATOR CODE (MOTHER)</xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="PersonBirthDateMother" type="ST" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:annotation>
               <xs:appinfo>PERSON BIRTH DATE (MOTHER)</xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="Postcode" type="ST" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:annotation>
               <xs:appinfo>POSTCODE OF USUAL ADDRESS (MOTHER)</xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="EthnicCategoryMother" type="ST" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:annotation>
               <xs:appinfo>ETHNIC CATEGORY (MOTHER)</xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="PersonDeathDateTimeMother" type="ST" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:annotation>
               <xs:appinfo>PERSON DEATH DATE TIME (MOTHER)</xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="MAT003GPPracticeRegistration" type="MSDSMAT003GPPracticeRegistrationType"
                     minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:element name="MAT101BookingAppointmentDetails"
                     type="MSDSMAT101BookingAppointmentDetailsType"
                     minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:element name="MAT112DatingScanProcedure" type="MSDSMAT112DatingScanProcedureType"
                     minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:element name="MAT201BloodGroupRhesusTest" type="MSDSMAT201BloodGroupRhesusTestType"
                     minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:element name="MAT203RubellaSusceptibilityTest"
                     type="MSDSMAT203RubellaSusceptibilityTestType"
                     minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:element name="MAT205HepatitisBScreeningTest"
                     type="MSDSMAT205HepatitisBScreeningTestType"
                     minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:element name="MAT210AsymptomaticBacteriuriaScreeningOffer"
                     type="MSDSMAT210AsymptomaticBacteriuriaScreeningOfferType"
                     minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:element name="MAT211HaemoglobinopathyScreeningTest"
                     type="MSDSMAT211HaemoglobinopathyScreeningTestType"
                     minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:element name="MAT301MaternityCarePlan" type="MSDSMAT301MaternityCarePlanType"
                     minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:element name="MAT303DownsSyndromeScreeningTest"
                     type="MSDSMAT303DownsSyndromeScreeningTestType"
                     minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:element name="MAT305FetalAnomalyScreeningTest"
                     type="MSDSMAT305FetalAnomalyScreeningTestType"
                     minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:element name="MAT306AntenatalAppointment" type="MSDSMAT306AntenatalAppointmentType"
                     minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:element name="MAT307MedicalDiag" type="MSDSMAT307MedicalDiagType" minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:element name="MAT309MaternityObstetricDiag" type="MSDSMAT309MaternityObstetricDiagType"
                     minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:element name="MAT310AntenatalAdmission" type="MSDSMAT310AntenatalAdmissionType"
                     minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:element name="MAT404LabourAndDelivery" type="MSDSMAT404LabourAndDeliveryType"
                     minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:element name="MAT408MCI" type="MSDSMAT408MCIType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:element name="MAT501FetusOutcome" type="MSDSMAT501FetusOutcomeType" minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:element name="MAT502BabysDemographicsAndBirthDetails"
                     type="MSDSMAT502BabysDemographicsAndBirthDetailsType"
                     minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:element name="MAT602PostpartumDischarge" type="MSDSMAT602PostpartumDischargeType"
                     minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:element name="MAT603PostpartumReadmission" type="MSDSMAT603PostpartumReadmissionType"
                     minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Please provide more details (schema, reduced sample, expected output) and it might come out, that T-SQL is the wrong language for this... Are there any other tools / languages available?

Comment: The schema is 77000 characters long? I'm told SSIS is the better approach.

Comment: With `.Net` you could - for example - create a `DataSet` from a valid schema and then try to load data into this schema... In SQL Server there is rather poor support of schema-data-validation

Comment: I'm afraid the data with originate in SQL tables, as I say the objective to output a result set into an XML file

Comment: What I understand: There are some database tables with data and you want to export them to XML (files). You are hoping for some kind of automatism when you use a schema to get this *easy going*... Correct so far? One XML per table or one big *inlcude everything* monster?

Comment: At the moment its exported from an Access database into one huge XML file which is sent/submitted to a national data centre. All we are trying to do is replicate the process using the SQL Server DW instead of the old now unsupported Access database. So as it stands we have a process which is working (but will soon be deprecated) and now need to try and replicate.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you do not need a schema at all. But - to be honest - I have very little experience with *Data Warehouse* version... AFAIK there is no automatic process like *Here are the tables, here is the schema, start the export* You'd need a (probably very complex)  query `SELECT ... FOR XML PATH(...)`, which produces exactly the XML you want to send to the data centre.

Comment: One question: How is the XML export done within Access?

Comment: Very long VBA Function

Comment: OK, this VBA is probably doing this on string level (concatenation of `"<SomeTag>" & SomeContent & "</SomeTag>"`? No help here... It might help to show a (reduced!) example of your XML and some input data. We can point you the way how to query this...

Comment: Post edited, does this help or you need more?

Comment: Appears this one is too hard as cant get a reply anywhere online on any site.

Comment: See my update! :-D

Comment: Huge thanks for this Shnugo, my task was just ascertain if it was possible to create an XML file based on data stored in SQL tables, so if this is possible it will be then up to a number of developers to come up with the actual design. You will have to forgive my knowledge gap as only been a BI Developer for 5 months and have no history prior of any developer related work. For whatever reason the company saw my potential as a very good Analyst and promoted me into a completely new role. I will learn and fast but if I ask what appears to be dumb questions, this is the reason why.

Comment: never mind... Good luck with this... I can see, that you invested quite some time in order to prepare a *good* question. But - from the above - I get the feeling, that you did not really know where you want to go. The title *how-do-i-validate-sql-tables-data-using-a-schema* does not point to *possible to create an XML file based on data stored in SQL tables* Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Appears this one is too hard as cant get a reply anywhere online on any site

Well, I cannot let this pass unchallenged :-D

*too hard* must be discussed... One problem is, that the schema, as well as the data you provide is not complete / invalid... In your attempts to shorten the provided sample data (which is great!) you created invalid sample data...
I would have to invest a lot of time first to understand what you really want and then to set up a *mock-up* project.

And now we are in the very center of *too hard*: I do not have the time for this...

SQL Server doesn't support a *built-in* schema check or schema related export automatisms. Therefore I told you in my first comment, that T-SQL might be the wrong tool...

You did not answer the question *Are there any other tools / languages available* ...

This code is a very simple C# code. It will create the internal structure of the dataset out of a schema and then load the given XML into this DataSet. This will fail, when the XML is not compatible. That might be a *schema check* for you.

```
        var ds = new System.Data.DataSet("TestSchema");
        ds.ReadXmlSchema(@"C:\SomePath\MotherSchema.xml");
        ds.ReadXml(@"C:\SomePath\MotherData.xml");
```

//The above in a `try-catch`, wrapped in a function might be enough as schema checked
//The following code would read the data into a string to check the success (totally untested...)

```
        var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        foreach (var t in ds.Tables) {
            var tbl = t as System.Data.DataTable;
            foreach (var r in tbl.Rows) {
                var rw = r as System.Data.DataRow;
                foreach (var c in tbl.Columns) {
                    var cl = c as System.Data.DataColumn;
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}.{1}: {2}",tbl.TableName,cl.ColumnName,rw[cl].ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
        var str = sb.ToString();
```

Finally (as pointed out in my comment *If I understand this correctly, you do not need a schema at all*) I'd create the XML using `FOR XML PATH` exactly the way you need it. That is roughly the same approach your complicated Access legacy code is doing: **Just create a correct XML**. Does the Access solution reflect any schema? Probably not... See what I mean?

### UPDATE Just to give you an idea:

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE DATABASE TestDB;
GO
USE TestDB;
GO
```

--Some tiny tables with tiny data. More columns are just *more of the same*...

```
CREATE TABLE MAT001MothersDemographics(ID BIGINT, Code VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO MAT001MothersDemographics VALUES(1111111,'1A1')
                                           ,(222222,'2B2');

CREATE TABLE MAT003GPPracticeRegistration(ID BIGINT,MotherID BIGINT,StartDate Date);
INSERT INTO MAT003GPPracticeRegistration VALUES(1,111111,{d'2001-01-01'})
                                              ,(2,222222,{d'2002-02-02'});
```

--I create the innner XML without namespaces as they seem to appear in the outer most node only...

```
DECLARE @MotherID BIGINT=222222;
DECLARE @innerXML XML= --without namespaces
(
SELECT '1.0' AS [MVersion]
      ,'5BC' AS [OrgCodeProv]
      ,GETDATE() AS [FileCreationDateTime]
      ,(
        SELECT ID AS LocalPatientIdMother
              ,Code AS OrgCodeLocalPatientIdMother
        FROM MAT001MothersDemographics
        WHERE ID=@MotherID
        FOR XML PATH('MAT001MothersDemographics'),TYPE
       )
      ,(
        SELECT MotherID AS LocalPatientIdMother
              ,StartDate AS StartDateGMPRegistration
        FROM MAT003GPPracticeRegistration
        WHERE MotherID=@MotherID
        FOR XML PATH('MAT003GPPracticeRegistration'),TYPE
       )
FOR XML PATH('MATHDRHeader')
);
```

--This will wrap the previously created XML with the `<MSDS:MSDS>` node

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi 
                  ,'http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/messages/MSDS-v1-0' AS MSDS
                  ,'http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/messages/MSDS-v1-0 ../Schemas/MSDSMSDS_XMLSchema-v1-0.xsd' AS schemaLocation)
SELECT @innerXML
FOR XML PATH('MSDS:MSDS');
```

--Clear Up

```
GO
USE master;
GO
DROP DATABASE TestDB;
GO
```

The result for this tiny portion look pretty much the way you need it:

```
    <MSDS:MSDS xmlns:schemaLocation="http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/messages/MSDS-v1-0 ../Schemas/MSDSMSDS_XMLSchema-v1-0.xsd" xmlns:MSDS="http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/messages/MSDS-v1-0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <MATHDRHeader>
        <MVersion>1.0</MVersion>
        <OrgCodeProv>5BC</OrgCodeProv>
        <FileCreationDateTime>2017-04-21T10:45:57.590</FileCreationDateTime>
        <MAT001MothersDemographics>
          <LocalPatientIdMother>222222</LocalPatientIdMother>
          <OrgCodeLocalPatientIdMother>2B2</OrgCodeLocalPatientIdMother>
        </MAT001MothersDemographics>
        <MAT003GPPracticeRegistration>
          <LocalPatientIdMother>222222</LocalPatientIdMother>
          <StartDateGMPRegistration>2002-02-02</StartDateGMPRegistration>
        </MAT003GPPracticeRegistration>
      </MATHDRHeader>
    </MSDS:MSDS>
```